# Why is the continuity of the binary operation required in the definition of a topological group?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

I'm currently studying topological groups, and I'm just wondering why we need continuity of the binary operation and the inverse map in the definition. What falls apart if we omit this condition? Why can we not just equip the group with any topology?

I know that if the inverse map isn't continuous then it is a paratopological group.

If possible, could you point me in the direction of resources that tackle this question?

Comment: Without it, the topology and the group operation have no relation to each other at all.  You need to tie them together so one informs the other.  That's why it is a successful theory.

Comment: What sort of results do you know about topological groups? If you don't tell us what you regard it as, how can we tell you how it falls apart?

Comment: Randall gives one example of a property which holds for topological groups but not for topological spaces with unrelated group operations, name *topological homogenetiy* (that is, the neighbourhood systems of any two points are isomorphic). Another example of such a property is that the fundamental group of a topological space is abelian.

Comment: If you use any textbook on topological groups, look at the results proved after (not only just after) the definitions and starting with "let $G$ be a topological group"... they are likely to make use of the continuity of the law.

Answer (score 10):

Think of it this way.  If you define a topological group to be merely a group with a topology on it, the master text of all results in the theory would simply be the master text of group theory results bound on top of the master text of all topological results.  There is nothing new, no new knowledge is created.  However, if you demand that the group structure interact with the topology, then suddenly you can prove new things about these objects (homogeneity of the topology, for one).  Now the master text of all results is much more than the union of the texts for group theory and topology.  The point is that the additional requirements give you more stringent hypotheses, allowing you to prove new results that weren't necessarily true otherwise.

Also, if you want evidence of all this, do a literature search for what you call a "paratopological group" and compare it to what you get for "topological group."

Comment: Okay, that seems logical. Could we not just allow the function to be discontinuous? It seems as though that could still connect the group and the topology.

Comment: Then you should propose a way to connect the group and the topology, and see what you can prove from it.  Maybe you find something new.

Comment: And think about how successful discontinuous functions are in proving topological results.  (They aren't.)

Comment: @e99 It's also worth adding that the notion of topological groups didn't appear randomly: rather, it was observed that lots of naturally occurring groups also come with topologies which interact with the group structure in a certain way (namely: the group operation and its inverse are continuous). More generality isn't inherently good; most of the time we want to find the "right" level of generality which lets us faithfully expand on some existing body of examples or results. Precisely because continuity is so strict it lets us prove things, and the result is that the general theory is "good."

Comment: +1 for @NoahSchweber's comment.  Abstraction for the sake of abstraction is a horrible way to make mathematics.

Comment: @Randall Well, it's admittedly incredibly fun. :P But it's important to note that it's (almost) never what *actually* happens or catches on.

Comment: OK, it's a horrible way to make mathematics that anyone is going to care about :)

Comment: @e99 the group operation and the topology will be a priori unrelated unless you *impose* a relation between them. If $S$ is a set, then any group operation $*$ along with any topology $\tau$ will give a "discontinuous topological group", and there is no inherent connection between them.